# Django management command mysql error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am getting

> django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: (1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")

when i try to run this script

```
class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        survey_res = SurveyResults.objects.all()
        for i in survey_res:
            rescount = SurveyResults.objects.filter(pkey=i.pkey, partner_id=i.partner_id).count()
            if rescount > 1:
                objs = SurveyResults.objects.filter(pkey=i.pkey, partner_id=i.partner_id)[:1]
                SurveyResults.objects.exclude(pk__in=objs).delete()
```

any solutions..?
I am trying to delete all records except the latest which have two fields in common.

Comment: dunno, but you could try splitting the last line line in 2 queries, first exclude them, then delete the objects.  (if that is where the error comes from)

Answer (score 0):

Well your MySQL version does not support those commands, so your choice is to
either use a different version of mySQL or not use 'IN' since that seems like
the culprit. So how about changing the last bit to:

```
if rescount > 1:
    objs = SurveyResults.objects.filter(pkey=i.pkey, partner_id=i.partner_id)[1:]
    for obj in objs:
        obj.delete()
```

That way you delete all but the first returned SurveyResults. Of course assuming that your results are ordered by latest first, since as you indicated you wanted to keep the latest.